# Result of complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I'm being tasked with showing that:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 z^n= \frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}$ for $|z|<1$

I know that the series converges and the completeness of $\mathbb{C}$ ensures that:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 z^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=0}^k n^2 z^n$.

However calculating $\sum_{n=0}^k n^2 z^n$ and taking the limit is a rather ugly endeavor (picture related).

Does anybody have a more elegant solution/hints?
[image: Complex power series]

Comment: Hint: start with $\,\sum n z^n = z \cdot \left(\sum z^n\right)'\,$ and repeat.

Comment: Thank you! I've got it now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\dfrac{1}{1-z}$$
for $|z|<1$, then differentiation gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$
or
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n}=\dfrac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$
another differentiation shows
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2z^{n}=\dfrac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}$$